# shadowsocks can not open https://scholar.google.com

Tags: vpn, google-scholar

shadowsocks can not open https://scholar.google.com
page show error:
Google Sorry…

We’re sorry…

…but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can’t process your request right now. See Google Help for more information.

the solution is: edit the VPS setting, `vim /etc/hosts` , under the ipv6, add below

```
2404:6800:4008:c06::be scholar.google.com
2404:6800:4008:c06::be scholar.google.com.hk
2404:6800:4008:c06::be scholar.google.com.tw
2401:3800:4001:10::101f scholar.google.cn #www.google.cn
```

My VPS server is `vultr`, it works. But I don't know whether other server is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is: edit the VPS setting, `vim /etc/hosts` , under the vpi6, add below

```
2404:6800:4008:c06::be scholar.google.com
2404:6800:4008:c06::be scholar.google.com.hk
2404:6800:4008:c06::be scholar.google.com.tw
2401:3800:4001:10::101f scholar.google.cn #www.google.cn
```

My VPS server is `vultr`, it works.

Reference: https://www.flyzy2005.com/tech/shadowsocks-google-scholar/

Answer (score 0):

make sure your vps has right ipv6 access
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.12.2-041202-generic x86_64)
ss version: shadowsocks-libev 3.1.3

## 1. add '-6' to resovle hostname to IPv6 address first

```
vi /etc/default/shadowsocks-libev
```

...

```
# add '-6' to resovle hostname to IPv6 address first
DAEMON_ARGS="-u -6"
```

## 2. `config.json` add item `"dns_ipv6": true`

```
vi /etc/shadowsocks-libev/config.json
```

...

```
"dns_ipv6": true
```

## 3. add mapping [ipv6: domain] in `/etc/hosts`

```
vi /etc/hosts
```

...

```
## Scholar
## type 'host google.com' to get the correct ipv6 address
## for me it's '2607:f8b0:4005:804::200e'
2607:f8b0:4005:804::200e scholar.google.cn
2607:f8b0:4005:804::200e scholar.google.com.hk
2607:f8b0:4005:804::200e scholar.google.com
2607:f8b0:4005:804::200e scholar.l.google.com

systemctl restart shadowsocks-libev
```

enjoy!

ref: https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev/issues/113